# ¿Por qué en mi select2 no puedo filtrar cuando lo cargo en un modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, select2

Al crear el **modal** con el plugin **bootstrap3-dialog** el **select2** no me sirve el filtrado. Pero el **select2** que esta afuera si sirve el filtrado sin ningún problema.

Pueden ver mi problema en el ejemplo.

```js
let data = {"results":[{"id":2,"text":"86414553 \/ Valero Mavarez, Jose Gerardo "},{"id":4,"text":"11652705 \/ Natera Hernandez, Alexis Rafael"},{"id":5,"text":"15956983 \/ Anka , Saadallah "},{"id":6,"text":"33528480 \/ Sanchez Riva, Jos\u00e9 Vicente "},{"id":7,"text":"19803223 \/ Osorio Rivera, Juan Pablo "},{"id":9,"text":"78020574 \/ Mendoza, Moises"},{"id":10,"text":"89608036 \/ Trujillo Betancur, Raul Ernesto "}],"pagination":{"more":false}};
    
$('#personal').select2({
  placeholder: "Elija...",
  allowClear: true,
  data: data.results,
  templateResult: function (data) {    
    // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
    if (!data.element) {
      return data.text;
    }
    var $element = $(data.element);
    var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
    $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);
    $wrapper.text(data.text);
    return $wrapper;
  }
});

$('#modal').on('click', function() {
    modal();
});

function modal(){
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Equipos',
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
    message: function(dialogRef) {
      dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0].setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');

      let form = $('<form/>',{
        'role'  : 'form',
        'class'  : 'form-horizontal'
      });

      div = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
          label = $('<label/>',{
              'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
              'text'    : 'Mecánico: '
          });
          label.appendTo(div);
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
              'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12 selectContainer',
          });
              let field_personal = $('<select/>',{
                  'class' : 'form-control',
                  'style' : 'width: 100%;',
              });
              field_personal.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      field_personal.select2({
        placeholder: "Elija...",
        allowClear: true,
        data: data.results,
        templateResult: function (data) {    
          // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
          if (!data.element) {
            return data.text;
          }

          var $element = $(data.element);

          var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
          $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);

          $wrapper.text(data.text);

          return $wrapper;
        }
      });

      return form;
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="modal" class="btn btn-default">Modal</button>
<br/><br/>
<select id='personal' name='personal' class='form-control' style='width: 100%;'></select>
```

Comment: Ño eso ya me pasó una vez y creo que lo resolví con css

Comment: crea un fiddle pa revisar el código

Comment: No te sirve crear el modal en el html y ponerle el `<select>` ? De esa forma yo lo probé y funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es agregar `tabindex: null`.

Quedando así:

```js
let data = {"results":[{"id":2,"text":"86414553 \/ Valero Mavarez, Jose Gerardo "},{"id":4,"text":"11652705 \/ Natera Hernandez, Alexis Rafael"},{"id":5,"text":"15956983 \/ Anka , Saadallah "},{"id":6,"text":"33528480 \/ Sanchez Riva, Jos\u00e9 Vicente "},{"id":7,"text":"19803223 \/ Osorio Rivera, Juan Pablo "},{"id":9,"text":"78020574 \/ Mendoza, Moises"},{"id":10,"text":"89608036 \/ Trujillo Betancur, Raul Ernesto "}],"pagination":{"more":false}};

$('#modal').on('click', function() {
    modal();
});

function modal(){
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Equipos',
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
    tabindex: null,
    message: function(dialogRef) {
      dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0].setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');

      let form = $('<form/>',{
        'role'  : 'form',
        'class'  : 'form-horizontal'
      });

      div = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
          label = $('<label/>',{
              'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
              'text'    : 'Mecánico: '
          });
          label.appendTo(div);
          div_field = $('<div/>',{
              'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12 selectContainer',
          });
              let field_personal = $('<select/>',{
                  'class' : 'form-control',
                  'style' : 'width: 100%;',
              });
              field_personal.appendTo(div_field);
          div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      field_personal.select2({
        placeholder: "Elija...",
        allowClear: true,
        data: data.results,
        templateResult: function (data) {    
          // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
          if (!data.element) {
            return data.text;
          }

          var $element = $(data.element);

          var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
          $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);

          $wrapper.text(data.text);

          return $wrapper;
        }
      });

      return form;
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="modal" class="btn btn-default">Modal</button>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Excelente! No había visto que se podía pasar ese tabindex en el dialog. Saludos!